# if checkbox is checked on .ready, addClass

Tags: jquery

I am loading a previously saved form for editing with values saved in my db.  I am stuck trying to get jQuery to determine the status of a checkbox upon page load.

Here is what I have done:

I loaded in the saved value (either 0 or 1) and then use php to check the box if value == 1.

```
<tr class="line">
  <td class="text-center"><input class="tax" type="checkbox" name="taxable" 
   value="{{$item->taxable}}"  <?php echo ($item->taxable == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/
  </td>
</tr>
```

Next I attempted to use jQuery to see if it the .tax checkbox was checked on document.ready() and then add the new class to the row:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($('.tax').is(':checked')){
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("extraClass");
    };
 //more jquery
```

My question: will the `.is(':checked')` run on document ready? If not, what is the proper way to see if the box is checked when the page loads?

If that part is correct, is `$(this).closest('tr')` the right way to add the new class to the row?

Comment: (1) It will be executed on DOM ready, since it is wrapped in the DOM ready function. You can easily check for that using a reduced test case in the form of a code snippet or a JSfiddle. And (2) yes, `.closest()` will add the class to the nearest (in terms of distance up the DOM tree) `<tr>` parent.

Comment: What did you try?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` isn't going to be `.tax`. It will be `document`.

You should instead say:

```
$('.tax:checked').closest('tr').addClass('extraClass');
```

```js
 $('.tax:checked').closest('tr').addClass('extraClass');
```

```css
.extraClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="line">
    <td class="text-center"><input class="tax" type="checkbox" name="taxable" 
     value="1"  checked="checked"
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input class="tax" type="checkbox" name="taxable" 
     value="0"  
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `$('.tax')` (`$(this)` scope doesn't apply to if blocks). So, maybe something like:

```
$(function(){ // aka $(document).ready(function(){
  var $tax = $('.tax');
  if ($tax.is(':checked')){
    $tax.closest('tr').addClass('extraClass');
  }
});
```

More concisely you could use:

```
$(function(){
  $('.tax:checked').closest('tr').addClass('extraClass');
});
```